# what xpath to select CDATA content when some childs exist

Tags: xpath, cdata

Let's say I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<a>
  <b>
     <![CDATA[some text]]>
     <c>xxx</c>
     <d>yyy</d>
  </b>
</a>
```

I can't find a way to get "some text". Any idea?

If I'm using **"a/b"** it returns also xxx and yyy
If I'm using **"a/b/text()"** it returns nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't actually select a CDATA section: CDATA is just a way of telling the parser to avoid unescaping special characters, and your input document looks to XPath exactly the same as:

```
<a>
  <b>
     some text
     <c>xxx</c>
     <d>yyy</d>
  </b>
</a>
```

(Having said that, if you're using DOM, then some DOM XPath engines fail to implement the spec correctly, and treat the CDATA content as a separate text node from the text outside the CDATA section).

The XPath expression a/b/text() should select three text nodes, of which the first contains "some text" along with surrounding whitespace.

Comment: ok so basically it looks like for any reason text() is a bit confused when a CDATA is part of the inner nodes and does not return anything. looks like the only proper way to handle this (and to be robust on any xpath engine) is to add a specific node to contain the CDATA section then... Thx!

Answer (score 0):

With the XPath data model the path `/a/b/text()[1]` should select a text node with the string value

some text

that is a line break, some spaces, the text `some text` followed by a line break and some spaces.

Comment: well... I'm not sure the order of the child is necessarily known so I can't be sure the CDATA section in on the first position...