# xpath failed to parse a SOAP response with CDATA

Tags: xml, soap, xpath

I have a SOAP response with this format:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:GetCampResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.ooredoo.com/">
         <return><![CDATA[<GetSomething>
<NOMBRE_P>3</NOMBRE_P>
<CATEGORY>HV</CATEGORY>
<P_E>
    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
    <P_ID>101</P_ID>
    <DESCRIPTION>some description</DESCRIPTION>
    <DATE_DEB>07/01/2015</DATE_DEB>
    <DATE_FIN>31/03/2015</DATE_FIN>
</P_E>
</GetSomething>]]></return>
      </ns2:GetCampResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I am trying to extract information from within the CDATA tag with the following commands which are failing:

```
/S:Envelope/S:Body/*/return/<![CDATA[<GetCampaignforMSISDN>/NOMBRE_PROMO

/S:Envelope/S:Body/*/return/*/NOMBRE_PROMO
```

So I wonder, whether extracting inforamtion from CDATA is supported in xpath. If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this instead :

```
//return/text()
```

Check [what xpath to select CDATA content when some childs exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745210/what-xpath-to-select-cdata-content-when-some-childs-exist)

Demo using [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) in a shell :

```
$ saxon-lint '//return/text()' /tmp/l.xml
<GetSomething>
<NOMBRE_P>3</NOMBRE_P>
<CATEGORY>HV</CATEGORY>
<P_E>
    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
    <P_ID>101</P_ID>
    <DESCRIPTION>some description</DESCRIPTION>
    <DATE_DEB>07/01/2015</DATE_DEB>
    <DATE_FIN>31/03/2015</DATE_FIN>
</P_E>
</GetSomething>
```

then:

```
$ saxon-lint '//return/text()' /tmp/l.xml > /tmp/ll.xml
```

then:

```
$ cat /tmp/ll.xml
<GetSomething>
<NOMBRE_P>3</NOMBRE_P>
<CATEGORY>HV</CATEGORY>
<P_E>
    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
    <P_ID>101</P_ID>
    <DESCRIPTION>some description</DESCRIPTION>
    <DATE_DEB>07/01/2015</DATE_DEB>
    <DATE_FIN>31/03/2015</DATE_FIN>
</P_E>
</GetSomething>
```

Finally:

```
$ saxon-lint --xpath '//NOMBRE_P/text()' /tmp/ll.xml
3
```

Comment: So I will get the Text within CDATA but I cannot parse it with xpath? (to get for instance the content of the variable NOMBRE_P)

Comment: I think you have to first extract the 'sub-xml' with the previous XPath in a string and do another XPath against this string that looks XML

Comment: Thanks, this a solution. But is possible to do this in one xpath command. I mean to apply xpath on the result of //return/text() without the need to do that in two times?

Comment: thanks, I will accept your answer as it is complete and will look further for own custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is what CDATA means. It means "the stuff in here might look like XML but don't be misled, I want it treated as character data without markup". It's an instruction to XML and XPath tools not to touch it with a bargepole. That's the only purpose of CDATA. If you want the content treated as XML and accessible to XPath expressions, then don't put it in CDATA.

Comment: Actually, I am receiving SOAP response from an external system on which I don't have the authority to make these changes.