# Talend / XPath: Get text of CDATA element in mixed context

Tags: xpath, talend

I've the following XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <ingredient id="1" weighting="1">
       <![CDATA[Name of ingredient 1]]>
       <blocked_search_terms><![CDATA[Term A, Term B, Term C]]></blocked_search_terms>
   </ingredient>
   <ingredient id="2" weighting="2">
       <![CDATA[Name of ingredient 2]]>
       <blocked_search_terms><![CDATA[Term E, Term F]]></blocked_search_terms>
   </ingredient>
  </product>
</products>
```

I am trying to get a list of all ingredient names via a tXmlMap component in Talend. The problem is, that I either get `null`  a concatenated string of the ingredient names and blocked search terms, e.g.

**Expression 1:**
`[xml.products:/products/product/ingredient]`

**Result 1:**
"Name of ingredient 1Term A, Term B, Term C, Name of ingredient 2 Term E, Term F"

**Expression 2:**
`[xml.products:/products/product/ingredient/text()]`

**Result 2:**
"null, null"

The result that I want to achieve is: 
"Name of ingredient 1, Name of ingredient 2"

What do I need to use to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot dive directly into the CDATA (see [what xpath to select CDATA content when some childs exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745210/what-xpath-to-select-cdata-content-when-some-childs-exist)) you *should* be able to achieve what you want with a indication of which element you want:

```
[xml.products:/products/product/ingredient[1]]
```